# Highchart Donut and Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to replicate chart similar to this (See Image Below). I've attached two separate plunkers for each chart.

What I am trying to achieve: [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnOHx.png)

**Donut Chart:** ===> See Comment below for Plunkr

```
 chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            colors: ['#F59640', '#A589D9', '#F16D64', '#35BEC1', '#EDEDED'],
            title: {
                text: '82',
                style: {
                    color: '#333333',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fill: '#333333',
                    width: '211px',
                    fontSize: '32px'
                },
                y: -30,
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'out of 100',
                style: {
                    color: '#333333',
                    fill: '#333333',
                    width: '211px',
                    fontSize: '28px'
                },
                y: 30,
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    innerSize: '60%',
                    outerRadius: '70%',
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                data: [
                    ['Collaboration', 19.61],
                    ['Reading Articles', 17.47],
                    ['Insight', 19.95],
                    ['Personalization', 25]
                ]
            }]
```

1. I'm trying to setup these values dynamically from an API. Total value is 100%, with 4-5 categories/series.
2. Its almost complete, just need to show blank value if items do not add up to 100%.

**Bar Chart:** ===> [Bar Chart Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0fo3VQqJcc8xKXH3vZvM?p=info)

```
            chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Collaboration', 'Reading Articles', 'Insight', 'Personalization'],
            visible: false,
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 25,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            },
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            },
            bar: {
                grouping: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Remaining',
            data: [5.39, 7.53, 5.05, 0],
            borderWidth: 0,
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
        }, {
            name: 'Remaining',
            data: [5.39, 7.53, 5.05, 0],
            borderWidth: 0,
            stack: 1,
            animation: false,
            color: '#CCC'
        }, {
            name: 'Completed',
            data: [{ y: 19.61, color: '#F59640' }, { y: 17.47, color: '#A589D9' }, { y: 19.95, color: '#F16D64' },
            { y: 25, color: '#35BEC1' }]
        }]
```

1. Unable to separate each bar like the image. Each bars are not stacking each other.
2. Also trying to match BOTH the labels above each bar as well as showing the Y labels under each bar with only the First and Last Label Showing.

**Unable to post more than 2 link at this time.**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Attached Missing Plunkr for Donut Chart ===>>[Donut Chart Example:](https://plnkr.co/edit/5ZsHoflpCu8jzm3J0Yui?p=info) <===

Comment: Last time I tried to achieve sth like that, I added the remainder (both in the donut and the bar chart) as yet another item...

Answer (score 1):

As sebastian mentioned, for the donut chart you can calculate the the remainder and add that as a data point

```
series: [{
    data: [
        ['Collaboration', 19.61],
        ['Usability', 17.47],
        ['Insight', 19.95],
        ['Personalization', 25],
        {
            name: 'Missing',
            y: 17.97, // calculate missing value and use as a data point
            color: '#ccc'
        }
    ]
}]
```

donut chart plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LiwDUGg0B6XeXRhXwFGE?p=preview

For the bar chart, you don't want the `plotOptions.series.stacking = percent`. This is converting your series data to a percent when you have already done that in the data you passed in.

Now you can set your Remaining series to the max value

```
{
    name: 'Remaining',
    data: [25, 25, 25, 25],
    borderWidth: 0,
    stack: 1,
    animation: false,
    color: '#CCC'
}
```

As for separating the bars & the labels, I would go ahead and make 4 separate charts and use an ngFor to load them into the DOM.

Comment: I'll make a plnkr if I get some free time, but this should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

**Bar chart only:**

You can achieve that kind of look by creating a separate series for every point and linking it to it's own (properly positioned) x and y axes.

**Live working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/41q6k8tc/

```
var series = [{
      data: [{
          y: 19.61,
          color: '#F59640'
        }],
        name: 'Complete',
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
      data: [{
        y: 17.47,
        color: '#A589D9'
      }],
      name: 'Complete',
      xAxis: 1,
      yAxis: 1
    }, {
      data: [{
        y: 19.95,
        color: '#F16D64'
      }],
      name: 'Complete',
      xAxis: 2,
      yAxis: 2
    }, {
      data: [{
        y: 25,
        color: '#35BEC1'
      }],
      name: 'Complete',
      xAxis: 3,
      yAxis: 3
    }];
```

For positioning axes I used `top` property (it's not documented in the API, but it works):

```
var xAxes = [{
  categories: ['Collaboration'],
}, {
  categories: ['Reading Articles'],
  top: '25%'
}, {
  categories: ['Insight'],
  top: '50%'
}, {
  categories: ['Personalization'],
  top: '75%'
}].map(function(axis) {
  // common options
  axis.height = '25%';
  axis.offset = 0;
  axis.lineWidth = 0;
  axis.tickWidth = 0;

  return axis;
});
```

For every series I created corresponding 'Uncompleted' series using this code:

```
for(var i = series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    series.push({
    name: 'Uncompleted',
    data: [25 - series[i].data[0].y],
    xAxis: series[i].xAxis,
    yAxis: series[i].yAxis,
    color: '#ccc',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    }
  });
}
```

These series are stacked.

Via `tickPositions` you can configure an axis to have only two labels.

Tooltip doesn't seem to handle top offset properly. Line `y = anchor[1]` needs to be changed to `+ (point.series.xAxis.top || 0) - (this.chart.plotTop || 0);` in `Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.refresh` core function.

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.xAxis
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.yAxis
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've implemented your suggestion and everything is working smoothly. However, I'm receiving an Error when I hover over Donut Chart, it does not seem to have any xAxis or Top property and as a result tooltip is not showing. No issues with Bar Chart.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. Does this problem still occur?

Comment: Problem still exist. Is there a way to keep the tooltips local to only the bar chart?  where point.series.xAxis.top, xAxis is undefined, when i hover over the donut (pie) chart. See plunkr below for reference.

Comment: I've added the following and seem to be working smoothly now.`if (point.series.xAxis) {y = anchor[1] + (point.series.xAxis.top ? (point.series.xAxis.top || 0) : 0) - (this.chart.plotTop || 0); } else {y = anchor[1] + 0 - (this.chart.plotTop || 0);}`